React App Routing does not work after Bitbucket pipeline build
this last couple of days been losing my mind trying to fix an issue regarding routing problems after building my app via Bitbucket pipelines.
The problem started when I changed the the router of the app from an old Router to React Router V6, I was deploying the App as a Web Service App with pm2 path --no-daemon --spa which so far was pretty good but after changing router stop working properly.
So I changed the deployment to an Azure Static Web App and deployed it with a staticwebapp.config.json
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "index.html",
    "exclude": ["/static/media/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,bmp}", "/static/css/*"]
  },
  "mimeTypes": {
    ".json":"application/json"
  }
}

My pipeline YML for BitBucket Deploying with SWA CLI
image: node:20

pipelines:
  branches:
    dev:
      - step:
          name: Build and Deploy React App
          deployment: Staging
          script:
            - unset CI
            - yarn install
            - yarn global add @azure/static-web-apps-cli
            - yarn build
            - swa --verbose=silly deploy "$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/build" --deployment token=$deployment_token --env production
          artifacts:
            - build/**

The weird thing is
If I do a local build and deploy it to azure static web app via SWA everything works.
But for example downloading the build from the pipeline artifact and running it locally the router is broken and does not act as an SPA like it is happening on the server.
Both build have the staticwebapp.config.json in place and they are equal.. blows my mind why this is happening.

If possible, share your Repo?

not possible, it is a company private repo

Problem solved.. the answer was right in front of me.. I was passing the env variables url's without the https://
After correcting that both app's on Azure App service and Static Web App are working properly
